# Show that if $\sup_{m \ge n} |f_m(x) − f_n(x)|$ converges in measure to $0$, then $f_n$ converges a.e

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions and define $g_n(x)=\sup_{m \ge n} |f_m(x) − f_n(x)|$. Prove that if $g_n$ converges in measure to $0$, then $f_n$ converges a.e.

Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$. Then there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge k$, $\mu(\{x: |g_n(x)|\ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2^{K+1}}$. Let $$E_k^{\epsilon}=\{x \in X: |f_m(x)-f_n(x)| \ge \epsilon \forall m,n \ge k\}=\cap_{m,n \ge k} E^{\epsilon}_{m,n}$$ where $E^{\epsilon}_{m,n}=\{x \in X: |f_m(x)-f_n(x)| \ge \epsilon \text{ for some  m,n $ \ge k$}\}$. Then $$E^{\epsilon}_{m,n} \subset \{x \in X: |f_m(x)-f_k(x)| \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\} \cup \{x \in X: |f_n(k)-f_k(x)| \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$$  which gives that $\mu(E^{\epsilon}_{m,n}) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ and therefore $\mu(E^{\epsilon}_k) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$. Let $E^{\epsilon}=\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}E_k^{\epsilon}$. Then $\mu(E^{\epsilon}) \lt \epsilon$. Then now I let $$E=\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Then $\mu(E)=0$ and $f_n$ is cauchy in $E^c$ and therefore convergent.

Is this alright?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The set $E^\epsilon_k$ defined is obviously empty. Can we find $x$ such that $|f_k(x)-f_k(x)|\geq\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C=\{x\mid\{f_{n}(x)\}_{n}\mbox{ is a Cauchy sequence}\}$. Note
that
$$
C^{c}=\cup_{k}\cap_{N}\cup_{m\geq N}\cup_{n\geq m}\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}\}.
$$
Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. We go to prove that
$$
\mu\left(\cap_{N}\cup_{m\geq N}\cup_{n\geq m}\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}\}\right)=0.
$$
Define $A_{m}=\{x\mid g_{m}(x)\geq\frac{1}{2k}\}$.

Note that for any $N$, 
$$
\cup_{m\geq N}\cup_{n\geq m}\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}\}\subseteq A_{N}.
$$

For, let $x\in LHS$. Then there exists $m\geq N$ and $n\geq m$
such that $|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}$. If $|f_{n}(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{1}{2k}$
and $|f_{m}(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{1}{2k}$, we will have 
$$
|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\leq|f_{n}(x)-f_{N}(x)|+|f_{m}(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{1}{k}
$$
 which is a contradiction. Hence $|f_{n}(x)-f_{N}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{2k}$
or $|f_{m}(x)-f_{N}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{2k}$. It follows that $g_{N}(x)\geq\frac{1}{2k}$.
That is, $x\in A_{N}$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since $g_{m}\rightarrow0$ in measure,
there exists $N_{0}$ such that $\mu(A_{N_{0}})<\varepsilon$.We have
$$
\mu\left(\cap_{N}\cup_{m\geq N}\cup_{n\geq m}\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}\}\right)\leq\mu(A_{N_{0}})<\varepsilon
$$
and hence 
$$
\mu\left(\cap_{N}\cup_{m\geq N}\cup_{n\geq m}\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}\}\right)=0.
$$

Now it is clear that $\mu(C^{c})=0$.