# If $sup_{m\geq n} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ converges in measure to $0$, then $f_n$ converges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question regarding the following post:
[Show that if $\sup_{m \ge n} |f_m(x) − f_n(x)|$ converges in measure to $0$, then $f_n$ converges a.e](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360095/show-that-if-sup-m-ge-n-f-mx-%E2%88%92-f-nx-converges-in-measure-to-0-the)

In the Answer it is mentioned that:

> Note that for any $N$,  $$ \cup_{m\geq N}\cup_{n\geq
> > m}\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}\}\subseteq A_{N}. $$
>
> For, let $x\in LHS$. Then there exists $m\geq N$ and $n\geq m$ such
> that $|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{k}$. If
> $|f_{n}(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{1}{2k}$ and
> $|f_{m}(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{1}{2k}$, we will have  $$
> > |f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\leq|f_{n}(x)-f_{N}(x)|+|f_{m}(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{1}{k}
> > $$  which is a contradiction. Hence
> $|f_{n}(x)-f_{N}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{2k}$ or
> $|f_{m}(x)-f_{N}(x)|\geq\frac{1}{2k}$. It follows that
> $g_{N}(x)\geq\frac{1}{2k}$. That is, $x\in A_{N}$.

I don't really understand the argumentation.
If $x \in LHS$, then there exists $m \geq N$ and $n \geq m$, such that $|f_n{n}-f_{m}|\geq \frac{1}{k}$ holds.

But why does he assume: If $|f_n(x)-f_N(x)|<\frac{1}{2k}$ **and** $|f_m(x)-f_N(x)|<\frac{1}{2k}$.

This then follows in a contradiction. Then it follows that $|f_n(x)-f_N(x)|>\frac{1}{2k}$ **or** $|f_m(x)-f_N(x)|>\frac{1}{2k}$.

I somehow have the feeling that I missed something.

Comment: This is a standard argument: if $|p-q|\geq a$ then necessarily $|p|\geq a/2$ or $|q|\geq a/2$. And the way you prove this is to argue by contradiction as done in the answer you're citing.